# Using Model.where with self.id or similar when exporting to .CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to export data to CSV based on the current case_main "show" page the export button is on. I believe I need something similar to the following, but I can't get any permutation of it to work. Any attempt at referencing self.id or :id results in an error or nil.

```
Billedtime.where(case_main_id: self.id).each do |time|
```

Using Billedtime.all.each do |time| lets the code run, but it obviously grabs everything instead of only billedtimes for the current case_main.

case_main has two one-to-manys, billedtimes and lineitems. I am trying to combine billedtimes + lineitems for a particular case_main into a single .CSV export.

Here is the code:

Model:

```
  def self.to_csv
    desired_columns = ["Client Code",
                       "Case Name" ,
                       "Date",
                       "Description",
                       "Hours",
                       "Charge",
    ]
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      # Header columns
      csv << desired_columns
      # Data columns
      Billedtime.where(case_main_id: self.id).each do |time|
        csv <<
            [
                time.case_main.client.client_code,
                time.case_main.case_name,
                time.billedtime_date,
                time.billedtime_description,
                time.billedtime_hours,
                time.billedtime_total
            ]
      end

      Lineitem.where(case_main_id: self.id).each do |line|
        csv <<
            [
                line.case_main.client.client_code,
                line.case_main.case_name,
                line.lineitem_date.to_date,
                line.lineitem_description,
                ' ',
                line.lineitem_total
            ]
      end
    end
  end
```

Controller:

```
  def show
    @case_mains = CaseMain.where(:id => @case_main.id).limit(5)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @case_mains.to_csv, filename: "case-#{Date.today}.csv"}
    end
  end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to "Export Billed Items", case_main_path(format: "csv") %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your model doesn't poses an *id* attribute, so `self.id` doesn't do the job. Instead you want to grab the current scope using [`all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all) and iterate through the collection using `each` or [`find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each). To prevent an 1+N query I've also added the needed `includes` call.

```
def self.to_csv
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << [
      "Client Code",
      "Case Name",
      "Date",
      "Description",
      "Hours",
      "Charge"
    ]

    all.includes(:client, :billedtimes, :lineitems).find_each do |case_main|
      case_main.billedtimes.each do |billedtime|
        csv << [
          case_main.client.client_code,
          case_main.case_name,
          billedtime.billedtime_date,
          billedtime.billedtime_description,
          billedtime.billedtime_hours,
          billedtime.billedtime_total
        ]
      end

      case_main.lineitems.each do |lineitem|
        csv << [
          case_main.client.client_code,
          case_main.case_name,
          lineitem.lineitem_date.to_date,
          lineitem.lineitem_description,
          ' ',
          line.lineitem_total
        ]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You might think, I don't want to export `all` records. However `all` (without receiver) operates on the current scope, so when you use it in the context `CaseMain.where(id: @case_main.id).limit(5).to_csv` you will grab the collection `CaseMain.where(id: @case_main.id).limit(5).all`.